# mysql_fetch_assoc can not access similars columns names

Tags: php, mysql

I have more than one table in my query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation r, users u ...")

while( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($fetch['u.id'] == $fetch['r.id']) 
    ...
```

And here is the problem I have same column name on tables and when i try to compare the id of reservations with the id of user i get only the id of users!!!

I can replace the '*' with the column names and to change their name with `AS (SELECT s.id as sid ...)` but is there any easier way?
For e.x:

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

If your two tables both have a column with the same name, then you're only going to be able to access one of those fields in an associative array - the key is the name of the field, so the first one is over-written by the second.

The quick fix is, as you say, to explicitly rename the fields so they don't clash. Though you might be able to work around it by using `mysql_fetch_array` - that will give you all the fields, but you'll need to access fields by index number; so if you change table structures, you'll need to re-write code.

The better way is not to have two fields with the same name in different tables, if at all possible - if they were called `reservationID` and `userID`, you'd avoid this completely. I try not to re-use fieldnames unless it's a foreign key.